# How can I select elements {a,b,c,d,e} in a list so that Or[GCD[a, b, c] == 1 , GCD[d, e] == 1]?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list

```
list = {{-4, -7, -3, 2, 5}, {2, 4, 2, 3, 9}, {2, 4, 6, 3, 5}};
```

I would like to select elements {a,b,c,d,e} from the list so that GCD[a,b,c]=1 or GCD[d,e]=1. I tried

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
f[{a_, b_, c_, d_, e_}] := {Or[GCD[a, b, c] == 1 , GCD[d, e] == 1]};
list = {{-4, -7, -3, 2, 5}, {2, 4, 2, 3, 9}, {2, 4, 6, 3, 5}};
f /@ list
```

I get

> {{True}, {False}, {True}}

How can I get like this?

> {{-4, -7, -3, 2, 5}, {2, 4, 6, 3, 5}}

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
ClearAll[f]

f[{a_, b_, c_, d_, e_}] := Or[GCD[a, b, c] == 1, GCD[d, e] == 1]
```

You can use `f` with [`Cases`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cases.html), [`Select`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Select.html) or [`Pick`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pick.html):

```
Cases[_?f] @ list
```

> ```
> {{-4, -7, -3, 2, 5}, {2, 4, 6, 3, 5}}
> ```

```
Select[f] @ list
```

> ```
> {{-4, -7, -3, 2, 5}, {2, 4, 6, 3, 5}}
> ```

```
Pick[list, f /@ list]
```

> ```
> {{-4, -7, -3, 2, 5}, {2, 4, 6, 3, 5}}
> ```

Alternatively,

```
ClearAll[g]
g = Or @@ CoprimeQ @@@ TakeDrop[#, 3] &;

Cases[_?g] @ list
Select[list, g]
Pick[list, g /@ list]
```

all give

> ```
> {{-4, -7, -3, 2, 5}, {2, 4, 6, 3, 5}}
> ```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use `f /@ list`, then change `If`

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];

f[{a_, b_, c_, d_, e_}] := If[Or[GCD[a, b, c] == 1, GCD[d, e] == 1],
    {a, b, c, d, e}
    ,
    Nothing
];

list = {{-4, -7, -3, 2, 5}, {2, 4, 2, 3, 9}, {2, 4, 6, 3, 5}};

f /@ list
```

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {{-4, -7, -3, 2, 5}, {2, 4, 2, 3, 9}, {2, 4, 6, 3, 5}};

f[x_] /; FreeQ[1] @ MapApply[GCD] @ TakeList[x, {3, 2}] := Nothing
f[x_] := x

f /@ list
```

{{-4, -7, -3, 2, 5}, {2, 4, 6, 3, 5}}

Or

```
g = x |-> If[FreeQ[1] @ MapApply[GCD] @ TakeList[x, {3, 2}], Nothing, x];

g /@ list
```

{{-4, -7, -3, 2, 5}, {2, 4, 6, 3, 5}}